# How to keep Visual Studio Code from loading Default profile instead of imported version?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I switched to a new macbook and I went through the steps of exporting my profile and successfully imported it into the new machine.

Problem is that VS loads the Default profile every time on startup.

I want to use the profile imported, every time...

There's no way to overwrite or delete the Default, so it's seemingly built in a way that requires the user to re-enable the desired profile every single time the app is started.

Does anyone know how to avoid the extra step or reconfigure so a chosen profile is the default?